# My Windows Host machine has almost constantly above 95% CPU utilization. How to reduce the high CPU utilisation?

Tags: windows, memory, hyper-v, cpu-usage

I have a host windows machine with the following details (72 GB RAM, other resources:
[image]

**Host**
: Socket - 1,
Cores - 4,
Logical Processors - 4

I have set up three hyper-v virtual machines on this host and these seem to be consuming too much CPU. But the vms themselves have been assigned the resources as following :
VM1 - 8GB memory, 2 Virtual Processors
VM2 - 16 GB memory, 2 virtual processors
VM3 - 16 GB memory, 2 virtual processors

Can some one help me in understanding if the really high CPU utilisation is because of these settings somehow ? how can i better assign resources to the vms so that my host CPU does not spike above 95% all the time.

Process details in Task Manager - vmmem high CPU consumption:
[image]

Please provide advice. I am really not sure how to reduce these performance issues.

Comment: well, apparently with your VM workloads, overbooking your CPUs by 100% (3VMs and 1 host, of which the VMs want 6 cores) isn't going to work.

Comment: I would start by disabling your VMs. Your processor isn’t up to the task of having three VMs running at the same time. You assigned 6 cores worth of processors and you only have [4 cores in total](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/77785/intel-xeon-processor-e5-1607-v2-10m-cache-3-00-ghz.html). You have assigned 120% of your processors capabilities and have pegged your system

Comment: Rough rule of thumb is to assign only about 1/2 your host resources to a VM . You can have multiple machines, just not all at once

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I will remove one vm and then assign 1 core each to the remaining two vms . Hopefully that reduces the load on host.

Comment: @JenkinsNewbie1989 - Windows requires more than one core, if you are running Windows within those VMs, you likely will experience very poor performance.  Most Linux distrubtions also require more than a single core to function.

Comment: Thank you @Ramhound for the follow-up answer. My team would like to order a windows server to run around ten windows 11 vms , each of it will run memory intensive applications. the plan is to assign 16 GB Ram to each VM.  What should the specifications be for a windows host that needs to run these many vms? Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: @JenkinsNewbie1989 - Determine how many cores each VM will require and order a processor or processors that will support that workload. You will likely find a single machine will be unable to support that heavy of a workload. 10 VMs would probably take at least 2 ESXi hosts to manage in the VMWare world and VMWare is a more efficient hypervisor